# FFMPEG trim video resulting not moving videos and black video with audio

Tags: ffmpeg

I tried to trim my video based on start and end time with the following code:

ffmpeg -ss 02:06:30.500 -to 02:06:32.417 -i movie.mp4 -c copy output.mp4

The output video is not moving video and some of them are black videos with audio. What should I do?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/is9hJ.png)

What should I do?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as explained by the ffmpeg tag: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/. Please delete this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this command :
`ffmpeg -ss 02:06:30 -to 02:06:32 -i movie.mp4 -c copy output.mp4`

Comment: It gives me the same result, black video with audio

Comment: in which software you are using this command ?